# How to show value of custom field in a variable product in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I try to show/print value of custom field in a variable product with:

```
get_post_meta();
```

However, I have not been successful, then I describe in detail the problem:

I added a custom field in all products (modelo) with next code lines in the archive functions.php:

```
function campo_personalizado_apg() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id' => 'modelo', 
        'class' => 'wc_input short', 
        'label' => __( 'modelo', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'campo_personalizado_apg' );


function campo_personalizado_variable_apg( $loop, $datos_de_variacion, $variacion ) {
    echo PHP_EOL . "<div>";
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id' => 'modelo[' . $variacion->ID . ']', 
        'class' => 'wc_input short', 
        'label' => __( 'modelo', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $variacion->ID, 'modelo', true ),
        'style' => 'display:block;', 
    ) );
    echo "</div>" . PHP_EOL;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'campo_personalizado_variable_apg', 10, 3 );


function guarda_campos_personalizados_apg( $product_id ) { 
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['modelo'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $product_id, 'modelo', $_POST['modelo'] );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $product_id, 'modelo' );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'guarda_campos_personalizados_apg' );


function guarda_campos_personalizados_variable_apg( $product_id ) { 
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['modelo'][$product_id] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $product_id, 'modelo', $_POST['modelo'][$product_id] );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $product_id, 'modelo' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'guarda_campos_personalizados_variable_apg', 10, 2 );
```

I show/print value of custom field in any .php archive with the next code lines:

```
if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
    echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'modelo', true);
    var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'modelo', true));

} else {
    echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'modelo', true);
}
```

In a single products the custom field is showing OK:

```
Modelo: p5r.2
```

The issue is whenn I try to show/print the value of custom field of a variable product:

Code line:

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'modelo', true);
```

Show/print:

```
array
```

Code line:

```
var_dump(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'modelo', true));
```

Show/print:

```
array(3) { [4299]=> string(3) "p5r.3" [4300]=> string(3) "p5r.4" [4301]=> string(3) "p5r.5" }
```

¿Can you help me? please.

(Sorry for my english).

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have saved an array of data in the meta field. Is the `modelo` field meant for each variation? Or for the parent variable product? (Sidenote: `$variacion->ID` will trigger warnings with WooCommerce 3.0 and should be replaced by `$variacion->get_id()`

Comment: @helgatheviking thanks for response. The field is for each variation.

Comment: Well that explains the problem. Your save routine is incorrect for variations. It makes sense that you'd end up with an array (keyed to variation IDs) as you'd get multiple `modelo` inputs... one from each variation. You need to use the [`woocommerce_save_product_variation`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/fe4a4a7e834198288ae26fc9131ef13b2d043669/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php#L4320) hook.